# System of congruences with non-pairwise coprime moduli

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

I have a set of congruences

```
x ≡ a1 (mod n)
...
x ≡ ak (mod nk)
```

And I want to find `x`, this can be solved by the Chinese remainder theorem and related algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Some examples: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

For this particular example:

```
x ≡ 1031 (mod 1473)
x ≡ 1141 (mod 1234)
x ≡ 50   (mod 1827)
```

All the algorithms that I have tried won't work, since the moduli are not pairwise coprime.
However, `1024360583` is a valid solution:

```
1024360583 % 1473 == 1031
1024360583 % 1234 == 1141
1024360583 % 1827 == 50
```

What algorithm could find such a solution ?

I have also implemented Garner's Algorithm from the Handbook of Cryptography: it didn't solve that example.

Comment: Answer on [math.se]: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1644698/1277. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120070/chinese-remainder-theorem-with-non-pairwise-coprime-moduli.